# Process Builder and Formula evaluates to true

Tags: formula, process-builder

Is there a trick to the Formula evaluates to true option in Process Builder? I tried the following formula:

```
[Opportunity].Record_Type_Name__c == 'New License' && [Opportunity].StageName == 'Closed Won - Not Paid' && NOT(CONTAINS([Opportunity].Type, 'Additional'))
```

The flow never gets triggered.

Comment: Is the Process activated ? Can you share more information in terms of screenshots ?

Comment: Unfortunately the Process is activated.

Comment: Formula is evaluated everytime, is that correct ? Whenever it is created and Edited ? right

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 1):

Try using one equal sign:

```
[Opportunity].Record_Type_Name__c = 'New License' && [Opportunity].StageName = 'Closed Won - Not Paid' && NOT(CONTAINS([Opportunity].Type, 'Additional'))
```

EDIT: Found this note in the [guide](https://help.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=015300000035wMDAAY)...

> There must be a space between the function’s parentheses and the
>   contents of the parentheses. For example, you’ll get an error for
>   TEXT([Account].LastModifiedDate) but not for TEXT(
>   [Account].LastModifiedDate )

EDIT2: Found an article that states picklist formulas are not supported and in the above guide there is a generic picklist not supported everywhere.

> Either tool will work however workflow may be the better option right
>   now. There is no function help in process builder so complicated
>   formulas may be difficult to build out. Also picklist formulas do not
>   work in process builder. - See more at:
>   http://gearscrm.com/overview-of-salesforce-process-builder#sthash.jbW4B8Kc.dpuf

Guide states:

> Processes evaluate picklist fields as if they’re text fields, so some
>   functions that normally support picklists may not support those
>   fields.

Comment: I originally had the single equal sign. Both save, but neither trigger the flow.

Comment: @victorcorey Looks like it's having issues with the picklist fields, if you use fields that are not picklist appears to work.

Comment: @victorcorey I can't find documentation directly from SalesForce but did find an article that specifically states it isn't supported. Maybe open a case to find out for sure.

Comment: So it looks like @victorcorey might need to add a text field that is the Opportunity stage turned into text for the formula in Process Builder then.

Answer (score 0):

I met this issue,too.

After I tried 5 case, I create a text field and using workflow field update to clone stage.

It's stupid but it's work.

Fortunately, criteria is easy to modify.